# How to detect passing over speedbreaker via android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am new to Android and not familiar with the different type of sensors. I am working on an App and part of it has to count the number of speedbreakers that a car will pass over during its journey.

- The phone will remain stationary in one position

I have tried using the accelerometer and tried to use a peak in vertical acceleration followed by a negative vertical acceleration as an indicator of a speedbreaker but there is too much fluctuation for an accurate result.

Here speedbreakers are smooth slopes of cement, usually a few inches high.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would start out with logging the accelerometer data (probably the speed data (from gps) as well) and manually marking the points where you pass a speedbreaker.

Then the first step would be to see if there is something to see here: maybe there is a clear 'signal' that's apart from the normal fluctuation, but you haven't gotten the tweaking right.

If there isn't, you can always see if there is something there that you haven't recognized. Some sort of of normal behaviour that stops for a bit. These can be harder to detect visually so you'd have to do something with the signal.

If you know nothing about signal processing it might be tricky, but as a random starting point, read up on how step-detection works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_detection

Some of the methods might be usefull to you. Look at the FFT, process your signal to filter out the points you need. Maybe even train a simple network to see if it finds anything going on at your desired points?